# MUMPS to Cache database migration

Tags: caching, nosql, database-migration, intersystems, mumps

A client wants information extracted from their MUMPS database and
transferred to a cache database, where do I begin and what are some
best practices I should keep in mind? (I am fairly new to MUMPS and
have been put on this project)

Answer (score 7):

Intersystems Cache' is an implementation of a MUMPS database, and its associated programming language (Cache' Objectscript) is a superset of the MUMPS programming language.  It is one of several different implementations of the MUMPS language standard.

When you say your client "wants information extracted from their MUMPS database and transferred to a cache database", the particular flavor of MUMPS database you are extracting data from is unclear.  Does your client want to pull data out of a GT.M system, a database running an older version of Intersystems Cache', or a system using some other flavor of MUMPS?

In the absence of specific information about the MUMPS database, it's hard to give specific best-practices.  Instead, the following general cautionary information is provided:

1. Depending on how you decide to do your Extract-transform-load process, the character encoding might be a problem.
2. All MUMPS implementations will store data in similarly structured data objects called "global" arrays, however, MUMPS databases can be configured to handle null array subscripts in different ways.
3. The maximum length of subscripts can vary based on database configuration.
4. The maximum length of a scalar value can vary based on database configuration.
5. If the information you want to move includes MUMPS routines or other code, you'll have a major project on your hands -- especially if the code accesses information outside of MUMPS (through TCP/IP connections or OS-level instructions).